# c# gridview not populating stored procedure sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, gridview

I am trying to populate the gridview with a stored procedure with the following code but whats happening is the gridview is not showing anything.

```
SqlConnection myConnectiona = new SqlConnection("user id=HOME-PC\\HOME;" +
                                   "password=password;server=HOME-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=tabrem; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30");

            SqlCommand pro = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[doctor]", myConnectiona);

            pro.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(pro);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();



        try
        {
                    myConnectiona.Open();

          da.Fill(dt);
          dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


        }
        catch (Exception w)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myConnectiona.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                myConnectiona.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Does the SP return something if you run it manually?

Comment: If you drop a break point on this line: `da.Fill(dt);`, can you see your result set?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do (if this is web forms)

```
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.Databind();
```

thanks

Comment: this is not web forms